# Jekyll/Ruby Kramdown Missing Dependency

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll, kramdown

I am struggling with trying to set up my first jekyll blog. I am trying to run jekyll server, but upon typing it into the terminal I get the error message:

```
You are missing a library required for Markdown. Please run:
$ [sudo] gem install kramdown
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Markdown encountered an error while converting '_posts/2013-08-15-immunize-canada-app.md/#excerpt':
                Missing dependency: kramdown
         ERROR: YOUR SITE COULD NOT BE BUILT:
                ------------------------------------
                Missing dependency: kramdown
```

I have already installed kramdown as it asks, but still receive this error. I found on another post to add gem 'kramdown' to the Gemfile, which still doesn't work. I am super new to Ruby/Jekyll, so any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Are you using bundle? do a `bundle update`, also, any kind of ruby manager like `rvm`?

Comment: Did your issue get resolved? I'm having the same problem and `bundle update` didn't help.

Comment: The top answer here really deserves to be selected as the best answer unless this did not resolve your issue.

Answer (score 47):

I think the problem is

```
gem query | grep kramdown
kramdown (1.8.0, 1.5.0)

bundle show kramdown
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/kramdown-1.5.0
```

as suggested in http://bundler.io/, always use `bundle exec`

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --watch
```

> In some cases, running executables without bundle exec may work, if
>   the executable happens to be installed in your system and does not
>   pull in any gems that conflict with your bundle. However, this is
>   unreliable and is the source of considerable pain. Even if it looks
>   like it works, it may not work in the future or on another machine.

Comment: This did the trick for me and when bundler is involved it would make sense to put this at the *top* of the troubleshooting list. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

This is most likely due to multiple installed `jekyll` gems. Jekyll can be installed multiple times because one may have

1. installed it by `gem install jekyll` on first try
2. added `github-pages` dependency in Gemfile as suggested by the guides

Therefore you should check if there are multiple installed copies. Run `gem list jekyll` from the shell, which outputs the following:

```
$ gem list jekyll

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

jekyll (2.5.3, 2.4.0)
jekyll-coffeescript (1.0.1)
jekyll-feed (0.3.1)
jekyll-gist (1.3.4, 1.2.1)
...
```

As you see, 2.5.3 and 2.4.0 are installed. I am running `gem uninstall`to get rid of one. The old version is a dependency of `github-pages`, therefore just uninstall `jekyll-2.5.3`.

```
$ gem uninstall jekyll

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. jekyll-2.4.0
 2. jekyll-2.5.3
 3. All versions
> 2
Successfully uninstalled jekyll-2.5.3
```

I have also uninstalled `jekyll-gist` the same way. This way you don't need to uninstall ruby at all.

Answer (score 3):

Delete **Gemfile.lock**

```
bundle install
```

run jekyll

Comment: Having just tried this before find the correct answer, I can verify that this will not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same problem in my environment:

```
$>gem uninstall kramdown

Select gem to uninstall:
 1. kramdown-1.5.0
 2. kramdown-1.9.0
 3. All versions
> 3

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
        kramdown-1.5.0

github-pages-39 depends on kramdown (= 1.5.0)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [yN]  y
Successfully uninstalled kramdown-1.5.0

You have requested to uninstall the gem:
        kramdown-1.9.0

jekyll-3.0.1 depends on kramdown (~> 1.3)
jekyll-2.4.0 depends on kramdown (~> 1.3)
markdown-1.2.0 depends on kramdown (>= 1.5.0)
test-unit-3.1.5 depends on kramdown (>= 0, development)
If you remove this gem, these dependencies will not be met.
Continue with Uninstall? [yN]  y
Remove executables:
        kramdown

in addition to the gem? [Yn]  y
Removing kramdown
Successfully uninstalled kramdown-1.9.0

$>gem install kramdown
Fetching: kramdown-1.9.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed kramdown-1.9.0
Parsing documentation for kramdown-1.9.0
Installing ri documentation for kramdown-1.9.0
Done installing documentation for kramdown after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

The problem is caused by 2 versions of `kramdown`.

So `uninstall` it first, then re-`install` it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem under OS X Yosemite, you should check your Ruby environment, see if `bundle install` command install your gems to the right place.

`which ruby`
`which gem`
`which jekyll`
`bundle show jekyll`

You may find that you are not calling the right `jekyll` you wanted to.

---

My solution:

`brew uninstall ruby (I installed ruby with HomeBrew)
brew install rbenv ruby-build (Use rbenv to manage system Ruby reference)
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.zshrc)`

**restart your shell**

`rbenv install 2.2.2 (Install Ruby v2.2.2)
rbenv global 2.2.2 (Make v2.2.2 the global default)
rbenv versions (Double check the output, whether the default is not system one)`